# Selenium Webdriver FindsBy annotation equivalent to driver.FindElements(...)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I'm playing around with PageFactory and object identification using FindsBy attributes. I'm liking it so far but I can't find a FindsBy annotation equivalent to the following which retrieves a list of elements from a table.

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#searchtable tr td a"));
```

If I try this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "#searchtable tr td a")]
public List<IWebElement> searchGridContents;
```

I get the error **"Type of field searchGridContents is not IWebElement or IList."**

PageFactory.initelements() looks for `typeof(IList<IWebElement>`) or `typeof(IWebElement)`). It seems that what FindElements above returns is

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>
```

Is there an annotation equivalent to this for PageFactory? I don't want to mix and match element identification approaches if I can help it.

Answer (score 1):

As is so often the case, the answer was contained in the question. The solution was to change it from `List<>` to `IList<>`

```
 public IList<IWebElement> searchGridContents;
```